# Python selenium webdriver wait is taking longer then it should

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

I have a 'WedDriverWait' for a presence of element which works fine if the page loads correctly but occasionally the page doesn't load (I just get a blank page) and then the 'wait' is about 5 mins rather then the 45secs I have it set to.

The code:

```
import selenium  
import random  
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  
import time  
import pyautogui  
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver.get('some webpage')  
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'body > div.content.login > div.wrap > div')))  
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_id ('data_body')  
compa = elem2.text  
if compa:  
    name()  
    click()  
    time.sleep(8)  
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])  
    try:  
        WebDriverWait(driver, 45).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'something')))  
        login()                          
    except Exception:  
        closing_page()
else:  
    moveon()
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: It could be that there is another - global - WAIT set up somewhere else in your code, that is 5 mins long.

Comment: There are some other waits that are not tied to this one, but they are all set to 45secs anyway.

Comment: Post your full code.